# Buying an additional Tango / Healing Salve during Tutorial Scenarios?

Tags: dota-2

I'm currently trying out DotA 2 (using the new Reborn Beta version), and since I'm new to these types of games, I'm working my way through the tutorials. One thing I've noted is that I can (and, to complete the tutorials, need to) buy stuff like a Tango and a Healing Salve right at the start of the tutorial. However, when I've used up the items, I can't buy any replacements, no matter how much gold I have available. The items are active (colored) in the shop, but nothing happens when I right-click on them. Am I doing something wrong, is there an in-game reason for this behavior that I just don't understand yet, or have I found a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure about the Reborn version, but in the tutorials in the previous version (before Reborn became the 'normal' version) you had to follow the specific prompting of the game. So it would not allow you to buy any items unless it wanted you to buy them. So even though that item was highlighted to indicate it could be bought, after you have bought it once you cannot buy another. Even with items such as a Tango, Salve, Mango, Clarity, or any other similar items.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bug in the tutorial, in standard games you can buy tangos, salves and clarities at anytime during the game.